# OpenManage: what's blocking my systems?

Tags: dell-openmanage

I drank the proverbial koolaid earlier this week and installed `OpenManage Essentials` on my desktop and updated / installed the agent on my servers. After doing the discovery on the various subnets I was surprised at how many systems were unrecognized. Im hoping there is a matrix somewhere that shows what's not working for these scenarios (NOTE: all these systems are Dell - ignoring the outsiders for now):

1. OM gets all system info but not the 'status'
2. OM gets the service tag but no status or other info
3. OM gets the network info (MAC address, IP) but nothing else
4. OM doesn't even 'see' a SAN (MD3000i)
5. ESX v2.x machines are found but can't be updated or categorized

In all cases I made sure that SNMP was running with the same community strings, IPTables wasn't getting in the way and DRAC is open and running.

EDIT: did some more digging. It seems the command 'invcol' from 'srvadmin-cm' is returning a fair number of errors. It's a 32-bit app so there was some finagling to get it to install (see [here](http://blog.christian-stankowic.de/?p=5210&lang=en)). Interestingly enough this same command returns some errors (though not as many) on systems that OM is working ok with.

Suggestions on what I'm missing here?